# How to convert image (28,28,1) to (28,28,3) in numpy

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, matplotlib, keras

I want to convert `mnist` dataset to `(28, 28, 3)` dimensions for fitting into the `tf.keras.applications.MobileNetV2` model, but this model requires the `(x, y, 3)` dimensions.

https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/images/transfer_learning

The first task is to extend the `mnist (28,28,1)` to `mnist (28,28,3)`, and then convert the `(28,28,3)` to `(x,y,3)`.

Here is the code for displaying `(28,28,1)` image:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = np.arange(28*28*1).reshape(28,28,1)

plt.figure()
plt.imshow(x)
plt.title(x.shape)
plt.show()
```

[image]

The following code is trying to display `(28,28,3)` but it is `NOT` converted from `(28,28,1)`:

```
y = np.arange(28*28*3).reshape(28,28,3)

plt.figure()
plt.imshow(y)
plt.title(y.shape)
plt.show()
```

[image]

How to convert the above `(28,28,1)` image to `(28, 28, 3)` and display in the `matplotlib`?

**Testing:**

Here is the testing for comparing the original image (`x`), numpy RGB image (`y`), tensorflow RGB (`z`), and the padding-zero images (`pad_zero`):

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import tensorflow as tf

x = np.arange(28*28*1).reshape(28,28,1)
x = x / x.max()

y = np.repeat(x, 3, axis=2)

z = tf.image.grayscale_to_rgb(tf.convert_to_tensor(x)).numpy()

def pad_with_zeros(a):
    a = a.copy()
    for ii, i in enumerate(a):
        for jj, j in enumerate(i):
            for kk, k in enumerate(j):
                if kk != 0:
                    a[ii, jj, kk] = 0
    return a

pad_zero = pad_with_zeros(y)

fig, axes = plt.subplots(1, 4, figsize=(16, 4))
fig.subplots_adjust(wspace=0.1, hspace=0.1)

plt.subplot(1, 4, 1)
plt.imshow(x)
plt.title("x: {}".format(x.shape))

plt.subplot(1, 4, 2)
plt.imshow(y)
plt.title("np.repeat: {}".format(y.shape))

plt.subplot(1, 4, 3)
plt.imshow(z)
plt.title("tf.image: {}".format(z.shape))

plt.subplot(1, 4, 4)
plt.imshow(pad_zero)
plt.title("pad_zero: {}".format(pad_zero.shape))

plt.show()
```

[image]

Why are all the image colors `different`?

The colors of `y` and `z` should look like the `x`, but they are `not`. Is there something wrong?

Comment: Your model probably wants RGB values and you are trying to feed it grayscale. How would you convert the two? Probably just replicate your one color channel into 3. ```np.stack((x,) * 3, axis=-1)```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use numpy's `repeat` function.

```
>>> x = np.ones((28, 28, 1))
>>> y = np.repeat(x, 3, axis=2)
>>> y.shape
(28, 28, 3)
```

[Here](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.repeat.html) is documentation of this method.

Comment: I tried the numpy and tensorflow solutions but found a problem, please see updated testing at the end of the post.

Comment: @stackbiz The difference in colors is because of how `matplotlib` handles grayscale (1 channel) and RGB (3-4 channels) images. There is an parameter to `imshow` method called `cmap` which is responsible of the way  `matplotlib` displays colors. As you can see, it wouldn't work with RGB because - "
The Colormap instance or registered colormap name used to map scalar data to colors. This parameter is ignored for RGB(A) data."

More on that here - https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.imshow.html

Comment: Also, the last image is red because padding with zeros changes your pixels from `[1]` to `[1, 0, 0]` which is red in RGB.

Answer (score 2):

Try `tf.image.grayscale_to_rgb`:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

(x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = tf.keras.datasets.mnist.load_data()
    
x_train = tf.image.grayscale_to_rgb(tf.convert_to_tensor(x_train)[..., None])
y_train = tf.image.grayscale_to_rgb(tf.convert_to_tensor(y_train)[..., None])

plt.imshow(x_train[0]) # take one sample
print(x_train[0].shape)
```

```
(28, 28, 3)
```

[image]

You can see what is happening under the hood of `tf.image.grayscale_to_rgb` [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/v2.9.1/tensorflow/python/ops/image_ops_impl.py#L2596).

Comment: I tried the numpy and tensorflow solutions but found a problem, please see updated testing at the end of the post.

Comment: Kindly ask a new question with your padding details and do not edit your question after the original issue was solved.

Comment: Thanks. I have updated the post and removed the padding zero question. And thank you for your help in Tensorflow. You have helped me a lot. But this time I have to choose one answer between you and @kacpo1. Please don't mind. Both of your answers are the acceptable answer.

Comment: @stackbiz No stress enjoy :)

Answer (score 1):

you can use

```
rgb_image = cv2.cvtColor(gray,cv2.COLOR_GRAY2RGB)
```

where gray is your gray image. You must import cv2